# How to convert a textview into imageview in android?

Tags: android, textview, imageview

I have a text view having text "Large Text". I want to convert it into an image view whose height and width are of the text view.The image should appear as like the text view i.e if the text is "Welcome to android",the image view should also display it in the same manner like text view on clicking the convert button.Please help me.my xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/relative" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
  />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="99dp"
    android:text="Convert" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you can use `Button` instead of `ImageView`

Comment: According to my requirement,I should use image view only.Thank for the reply.

Comment: can you say what is your requirement that you can't use Button?

Comment: convert the text to an image view, or mostly to an image?

Comment: If the length of the text is beyond the width of the activity,then it comes into the second line.But i want it to be in a single line whatever the length of the text is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use.
Bitmap bmp = view.getDrawingCache();
ImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);